# Как долго может хранится история поиска и просмотра в гугле, ютьюбе, если не удалять её?

Tags: сеть

Стало интересно, сколько времени может хранится история поиска и просмотров в ютьюбе, история поиска в гугле, если её не удалять. До того момента, пока ты сам не почистишь, либо же автоматом через некоторое время?

Answer (score 0):

История в аккаунте Google "Мои действия" не совсем история. Часть данных может не отображаться, но будет использована для персонализации поисковой выдачи и рекламы. С учётом бесплатных 15 ГБ на Google Drive  считайте что бесконечно.